# Most common diseases associated with low GGT

Tags: liver

What are the most common diseases associated with low GGT - Gamma glutamyltransferase? Can you provide a short bullet point list?

Comment: Can you expand the acronym?

Comment: Since you tagged your question "liver" I assumed that you meant gamma glutamyltransferase by GGT and expanded the acronym. If I'm wrong, please roll back the edit. For future reference, even if you thing that the acronym is a well known one it is always a good practice to spell out the whole name the first time you mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this website (http://www.palpath.com/index.htm), which regroups a group of pathologists:

> **Following diseases/conditions can be associated with low GGT**
>
> - some cases of treatments to reduce high triglycerides also decrease    the GGT.
> - levels fall (but not necessarily below normal) after meals
> - hypothyroidism
> - hypothalamic malfunction
> - low levels of serum magnesium

They cite following sources, so possibly, these might give more details:

- Burtis CA & Ashwood ER, Tietz Textbook of Clinical Chemistry, 3rd
  Edition, 1999.
- McKenna and Keffer, The Handbook of Clin. Path., 2nd Ed. (EBS's
  office)
- hepatic lab tests, Practice Guidelines, National Academy of Clinical
  Biochemistry (NACB), USA.